# Query a DHCP server for a specific mac tied to a specific host name

Tags: dhcp, netsh

I need to query a dhcp server for a specific remote computers mac and then use that mac in another command line to send a WOL packet. I am trying to run a easy to use WOL interface that uses checkboxes to mark remote machines to wake up. My existing program works I am just trying to add this functionality.

I can run the netsh command "dhcp server \\dhcpname scope x.x.x.x show clients 1" without a problem. But i am uncertain how to sort the values returned to pull the specific mac and then use that value in another command line to send the magic packet. Its probably an easy solution but it beyond me. Can anyone help? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out myself, frustration is the mother of answers and migraines

set netsh=netsh dhcp server \dhcpserver scope x.x.x.x show clients 1

FOR /f "tokens=5 delims= " %%G IN ('%netsh% ^|find /i "computername"')

then just finish the loop with DO using %%G as the mac variable